# PowerShell - Removing old Teams installation folders in C:\Users\Appdata\Local

Tags: powershell, security, version, microsoft-teams, appdata

Is there a way to remove old installations of Teams from every C:\users folder?

I've been messing with the below, but it doesn't appear to iterate properly through each user folder.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\users\*\appdata\local\microsoft\teams" -Recurse | where { (get-item C:\users\*\appdata\local\microsoft\teams\current\Teams.exe | % {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion}) -lt 1.6.00.18681} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Please help! Thanks so much.

Comment: The `%` needs to be `Where-Object` when comparing the version number. And, the `ProductVersion` is a `[string]` type. I am not sure that a simple string comparison will be correct. I may need a cast to a `[version]` type. For testing, using `-WhatIf` on the `Remove-Item` might be prudent.